# Grails best practice for data list retrieving

Tags: grails

I would like to know which one is considered a better practice in Grails:

1) In a controller, to retrieve data using findBy methods and return a map for the corresponding view to render- e.g Users.findByLogin() -  or

2) Leave it to the view iterate over the data using g:findAll - e.g.

```html
<g:findAll in="${users}" expr="${it.login?.contains('John')}">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Option 1, definitely not #2.

Comment: and if for whatever reason you need to do such thing at that layer - simply pass the id or in your case name 'john' to a tag lib. The taglib can then inject a service like Joshua has suggested below, do lookup and return result back to your display.

Comment: I really don't need to. I was rather curious about the real usefulness of g:findAll and the sensible use we can make of it. But apparently it all comes down to MVC Model 1 vs. MVC Model2, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use a `controller` to create the `model` your `view` will render. The source for the data can be a `service` or GORM calls (e.g. `findBy`).